# Do I have to sign a check with "For Deposit Only" and Account number?

Tags: banking, check, endorsement

My business processes a lot of checks and I was thinking about ordering one of those For Deposit Only stamps.

If I get it to say with account number:

"FOR DEPOSIT ONLY

## 00000000"

Is that enough?  Do I have to sign in addition to this?  Do I have to include the business name also in the endorsement?

Answer (score 8):

> Is that enough? Do I have to sign in addition to this? Do I have to
>   include the business name also in the endorsement?

Ask your bank. You need to ask them what is the information they want you to include on the stamp  to properly endorse the check. You also need to ask them if it changes if you are scanning the checks and sending them the images.

Once you know what they require, you also need to make sure that whatever stamp you order, it fits within the space designated on the back.

Answer (score 5):

Since you didn’t tag with a country code, you are likely to get US centric answers.

Mine is that when I opened a business checking acct, I was given a stamp. business name, acct number, for deposit only. I stamp and deposit via phone app, which snaps pictures of both sides. No signature.

Comment: My self-purchased stamp has only "for deposit only" and the account number. No problems with that configuration either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any benefit to putting the least amount of text you can on a stamp. It normally says

> For Deposit Only to
>
> ABC Bank
>
> Account 1234
>
> XYZ Company

The bank name helps if the check were to be misdirected in processing and the account name for verification if your account number is miskeyed somewhere. This helps prevent headaches and lost checks. Ask your bank for the final word.

However, there is one [important recent change](http://www.thepaymentsreview.com/compliance-corner-new-rdc-rules) due to [potential fraud](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105382/what-could-be-the-consequences-of-accidentally-receiving-money-for-a-check-twice). If you are using mobile or remote check deposit, you should now endorse it

> For Mobile Deposit Only To

or

> For Remote Deposit Only To

or your check may be rejected by your bank.

Answer (score 0):

The Federal Reserve Board implemented new rules in July 2018 that are changing the requirements banks are imposing for deposits through mobile apps. These are mostly to try to mitigate the risk of you trying a scheme to deposit the same check in multiple banks before they figure out what you did.

> "...under the new rules, if the member wrote “for mobile deposit only”
>   or similar on the back of the check deposited via RDC, Financial
>   Institution A would not be liable if the member later managed to
>   deposit the paper version of the check at Financial Institution B."

Source:  ["CUs Begin Using New Rules 'for Mobile Deposit Only'"](https://www.cutimes.com/2018/07/09/cus-begin-using-new-rules-for-mobile-deposit-only/?slreturn=20190121144232) - Credit Union Times